# Is it possible to add a label with in inside a image programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios

[image]

I required to set time where **88:88** is there within an image.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You just need to have the image without the `88:88`, add a `UILabel` with the text you want and add it as a subview of your `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to display the image (without the text) inside an `UIImageView`, and add an `UILabel` as subview.

```
let image = UIImageView()
image.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)

let label = UILabel()
label.text = "88:88"
image.addSubview(label)
label.frame = image.frame
label.textAlignment = .center
```

Note: Setting the label with the same frame as the image view and the text alignment to center, ensure the label is centered inside the image (both vertically and horizontally).